# Why 'msbuild' command doesn't redirect its output to Preview app, while 'man' command does?

Tags: macos, terminal, msbuild, mono, pipe

When I open the 'Terminal' from my 'El Capitan' OS X, and issue the following command:

```
 $man -t cd | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app
```

It opens the Preview app with the documentation of 'cd'. But when I issue the following command:

```
 $msbuild | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app
```

It just opens the Preview with NOTHING. While 'msbuild' itself outputs the following in Terminal:

```
$ msbuild
 Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.40-preview+ge6c3a1f9e4 for 
 Mono
 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

 Build started 12/26/2018 8:08:03 AM.
 Project "/Users/amed/Projects/SunCRC/source/SunCRC.sln" on node 1 
 (default targets).
 ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
 Building solution configuration "Debug|x86".
 Project "/Users/amed/Projects/SunCRC/source/SunCRC.sln" (1) is 
 building "/Users/amed/Projects/SunCRC/source/SunCRC/SunCRC.csproj" 
 (2) on node 1 (default targets).
 ResolveAssemblyReferences:
 A TargetFramework profile exclusion list will be generated.

 ....


 GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
 Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all 
 output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
 CoreCompile:
 Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date 
 with respect to the input files.
 CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
 SunCRC -> 
 /Users/amed/Projects/SunCRC/source/SunCRC/bin/Debug/SunCRC.exe
 Done Building Project 
 "/Users/amed/Projects/SunCRC/source/SunCRC/SunCRC.csproj" (default 
 targets).
 Done Building Project "/Users/amed/Projects/SunCRC/source/SunCRC.sln" 
(default targets).

  Build succeeded.

  "/Users/amed/Projects/SunCRC/source/SunCRC.sln" (default target) (1) 
  ->
   "/Users/amed/Projects/SunCRC/source/SunCRC/SunCRC.csproj" (default 
   target) (2) ->
  (ResolveAssemblyReferences target) -> 


/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.16.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2130,5): warning MSB3256: No assemblies were read in from the redist lists. A TargetFramework profile exclusion list could not be generated.  [/Users/amed/Projects/SunCRC/source/SunCRC/SunCRC.csproj]

1 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.01
```

Is there any parameter should be passed to 'msbuild' to make the Preview open with the same output?

Comment: You can not "open" console-based std-out|err in preview, you could redirect the output to a text file and then open that in preview.

Comment: But how to preserve the color of output when redirecting to text files?

Comment: To preserve the term/ANSI colors you could do something like this:  https://superuser.com/questions/465718/copy-colorful-terminal-emulator-text-output-and-paste-as-html